# Angularjs browser back to previous website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with the browser back button on our Angularjs application.  Here's the basic setup.  We multiple pages (really states...) that perform a validation of the token on the client computer.  Here's an example of one such state:

```
theApp.controller('someController',
  ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$log', 'authenticationFactory','myFactory',
    function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, log, authenticationFactory, myFactory) {
      log.debug('someController');

      authenticationFactory.validateToken()
        .then(success => {
          return filesFactory.getFileContentDetails($stateParams.fileId);
        })
        .then(response => {
          $scope.stuff = response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          $state.go('login', { error });
        })
        .finally(() => {
          spinnerFactory.hide('loading');
        });
      }]);
```

Here is a snippet of the defined login state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url:         '/login',
    templateUrl: 'pages/login/login.html',
    controller:  'loginController',
    params:      {
      error: null
    }
  }).state('someresource', {
    url:         '/someresource/:fileId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/someresource/someresource.html',
    controller:  'someController'
  });
```

And, here is some of the login controller:

```
theApp.controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$state', '$log', 'authenticationFactory', 'statusPopupFactory',
    function ($scope, $state, log, authenticationFactory, statusPopupFactory) {
      log.debug('loginController');
      if ($state.params.error) {
        log.error($state.params.error.data);
        statusPopupFactory.setStatus('danger', $state.params.error.data);
      } else if (localStorage.token) {
        authenticationFactory.validateToken()
          .then(user => {
            $state.go('home');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            log.error(`Token validation error: ${error.data}`);
          });
      }
    }]);
```

So as it is, everything behaves as it should... can login, states transition, etc.  You can hit URL directly which would bring up the state controlled by `someController`, rather than going through the normal app menuing system (ie, I could just navigate to https://theApp/someresource/1, which is run by `someController`).

When this is done, and they do not have a token (or it's expired or whatever other reason...), they get bumped to the state login.  At this point, if they hit the browser back, the browser is trying to redirect them to the previous state in which they came from, rather than the website they came in from.  When it tries to go to the previous state, it merely attempts to do revalidation of token, that fails, and just bounces them back to login once again.  So it's a cyclical loop.

The issue is that from the "login" page at this point, they can't actually navigate back to the previous website.  It feels like they are "trapped" in the site, never to get out of the login page unless you simply manually change the URL or close tab, etc.

**How can I go about solving this?**

My initial thoughts were that when the login state loads, I could somehow look at all the browser history, and remove all previous states for the application, but preserve any states that are not from the same host url.  That way from login, they could "browser back" just fine.  However I've exhausted lots of searching in trying to figure this out and... thus here I am.

Comment: This is normal browser behavior, not some AngularJS quirk. Users should be quite accustomed to it. In most browsers, users can click and hold the back button to get a list of previous pages.

Comment: While I see what you're saying, I'd wager to say many users aren't generally accustomed to doing that.  I get it's a simple thing, but not being able to simply do a single click of back would cause frustration.